# How to make onclick automatically through onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a `href` link and I would like it to be clicked when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#someLinkId').click();
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#someLinkId').trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#whateverid").trigger("click");
```

Where "whateverid" is the ID of the anchor tag, or whatever other selector you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myLink").trigger('click');
});
```

as you can read in: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of loading the page if you're going to navigate away from it immediately?

In addition to jQuery's triggering abilities, you could do:

```
<body onload="window.location.replace('http://example.com/');">
```

or:

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'http://example.com/';">
```