# Using to jQuery to fire an anchor tag 'click' on load

Tags: jquery, html, html-email

Disclaimer:
Ok I know that this is being discussed in the thread linked below, but it isn't solving my problem.
[How to make onclick automatically through onload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098019/how-to-make-onclick-automatically-through-onload-function/8825612#8825612)

Issue:
I want to include a 'tweet' button in an HTML email. Obviously since you cannot run js in most clients this isn't feasible. My theoretical solution to have an image link that says tweet that opens a new window who's sole purpose is to house and fire a jQuery click event on an actual tweet button.

I'm trying to use this bit of simple syntax to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#autoClick2').trigger("click");
});
```

with this `<a id="autoClick2" href="mailto:nothing@nothing.com">ugh</a>`

I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#autoClick2').click();
});`
```

No dice on either, anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you code the tweet button yourself? It is actually a button or is it just an `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems a roundabout way of accomplishing your task, which is, if I understood correctly, simply *to tweet something*. Why not simply make that in-email "Tweet this" image a link to Twitter's share URL? Here's a quick (and dirty) example using the URL from this question:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f8826132%2f114900&amp;text=Using%20to%20jQuery%20to%20fire%20an%20anchor%20tag%20%27click%27%20on%20load">
<img src="http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.ico" alt="Tweet this" />
</a>
```

Implemented:

[http://a4.twimg.com/images/favicon.ico Tweet this](http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f8826132%2f114900&text=Using%20to%20jQuery%20to%20fire%20an%20anchor%20tag%20%27click%27%20on%20load)

**For a more refined example**, see the "Build Your Own Tweet Button" section of [Twitter's development documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button).

Comment: Thanks all for the input. @msanford, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was going to build my own buttons anyway. Cheers.

Comment: This is how I had to code my own Tweet buttons before I knew any JavaScript, anyway :) Thanks for accepting so fast, and, most importantly, **for providing context** in your question (so, +1 for that!) Without context, my answer would have been significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers block the automatic opening of links by a triggered click event to prevent any number of security problems.  Instead of using `.click()`, you should just use `window.open`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Most browser's security won't let this pass. It's too much navigation from one sole event. You can't just daisy-chain a user wherever you want them to go.