# Javascript automatically click onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am at a loss here, I am modifying a template for whmcs and I am trying to get an onclick event to launch when the page loads. I have tried the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098027/3847188) but for the life of me I can't get it to work. How would you do this?

Here is the code:

```
<div><label><input type="radio" name="domainoption" value="incart" id="selincart" onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none';document.getElementById('transfer').style.display='none';document.getElementById('owndomain').style.display='none';document.getElementById('subdomain').style.display='none';document.getElementById('incart').style.display=''" /> {$LANG.cartproductdomainuseincart}</label></div>
```

I got it to work guys. I appreciate all your help. Turns out, its a SMARTY template, so it was not parsing the {} correctly. Hence why it didn't work with any examples and 3 hours of me struggling for a stupid problem. I wasn't using {literal}.

Thanks for those that didn't put me down for asking a stupid question...

Comment: And where's the code to trigger the click?

Comment: Why not move the onclick actions into their own function which you then call on startup as well?

Comment: this is not hard to research...show us the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute javascript on page load, you can use body onload

```
<script>
function load()
{
alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>


<body onload="load()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with Jquery, Use trigger to run your click codes :

Example :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#yourId').trigger("click");
    });
```

Comment: Should include in answer that there is a library dependency when you provide jQuery solution for question that isn't tagged jQuery